# Почему данные в базу добавляються непонятные символы?

Tags: php, utf-8, mysql

Почему данные в базу добавляються непонятные символы?

Comment: Потому что ты их добавляешь?

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте кодировку таблицы, php файлов, html страниц (и кодировок на странице). Везде ли они совпадают?

Comment: Да везде стоит utf8

Answer (score -2):

Если используется форма, то в теге form напишите

```
accept-charset="utf8"
```

должно заработать

Comment: Ответ не полный.